# Draw 2 rectangles from a list of 3

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw random rectangles after the user presses a key.
I'm struggling to find a way to randomly pick the rectangles. What is the best way to do that?

There are 4 possible rectangles. If the user presses a certain key, I want to randomly draw two rectangles in a, b and c, and if he presses a different key I want to draw 2 rectangles in a, b, and d.

I'm drawing the rects via pygame.draw.rect(-parameters-).
Is it possible to assign every different rectangle draw to a variable and put them into a list, and then call them doing random.choice() onto that list?

```
def pick2():
    a = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0,0,255), (650, 600, 450,70))
    b = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0,0,255), (650, 750, 450,70))
    c = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0,0,255), (100, 750, 450,70)) 
    d = pygame.draw.rect(fenster, (0,0,255), (650, 750, 450,70))
    list = [a,b,c,d]
    random.choice(list)
    random.choice(list)

    pygame.display.update()
```

I tried a bit but did not get it to work.
I also want the second random.choice(list) to have a different output then the first one.

Is it even possible to assign pygame functions to a variable like that?

What I basically want is to only execute two of the three rectangle draws, chosen at random.

Can someone help?

Comment: You call `random.choice()` but ignore its return value. Also note that you might choose the same rectangle twice. You can fix this by using `random.choices()` instead.

Comment: "Is it even possible to assign pygame functions to a variable like that?" You aren't assigning a function to a variable like you ask. Instead you are assigning the functions **return value** to a function. You need to do the same with the return value from `random.choice()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
a = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0,0,255), (650, 600, 450,70))
```

This will call `pygame.draw.rect()` and assign its return value to the variable `a`. Note that by calling `rect()` function, you immediately draw the rectangle. This goes for all of the following calls as well. While it is possible to assign the rectangles to variables in this way, it will still draw all of them. In order to do what you want, you need to select the two rectangles to draw first, then draw only the two chosen rectangles. One way to do this is to store the coordinates of each rectangle in a list:

```
rects = [(650, 600, 450,70), (650, 750, 450,70), (100, 750, 450,70), (650, 750, 450,70)]
```

Now you can choose two rectangles:

```
chosen = random.sample(rects, k=2)
```

I use `random.sample()` to ensure that I don't get the same rectangle twice. Also I assign the return value to a variable in order to capture the randomly chosen rectangles

Finally draw those rectangles:

```
for rect in rects:
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0,0,255), rect)
```

Note that I choose two rectangles out of all 4 of your examples. If you want to choose 2 out of 3, then just change the `rects` list as appropriate.

I strongly suggest that you check out the official Python tutorial at http://python.org. It will help you understand functions and return values in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the choice. You're just calling `random.choice`, what you should do is something like this.

```
random_choice = random.choice(list)
random_choice_2 = random.choice(list)
```

Then you can do whatever you want with those two variables.

Comment: That might get the same rectangle twice. Better is [`random.sample(list_of_rectangles, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)